# XML site map generator can't crawl my website

Tags: seo, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

We used https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ to crawl our website to create a sitemap but for some reason, only a page can be found, but we have more than just a page. And this is our site (https://www.wgvs.com/). I assume there is something to prevent other robots to crawl our site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website is dynamically loaded using JavaScript. That means that most bots/tools will not be able to crawl your site.

The solutions to this are to either use server-side prerendering or change the architecture of your site so that it is no longer an SPA.

Comment: that also includes Google's bot?

Comment: @LongNguyen Google's bot is an exception and it should be able to crawl it. Just make sure that your site renders properly by testing it in Google Search Console.

Comment: In our case, do you what is the best way to generate the xml sitemap? Thanks

Comment: @LongNguyen It depends on what server-side framework (or integrated hosting service) you are using for your website. Each framework usually has its own process for generating a sitemap. If your server-side is totally static, you will need to run a deploy-time script or add some server-side code to generate the sitemap ahead-of-time or dynamically, respectively.